# Rest Callout Remote Site error

Tags: apex, callout

I have already added my url to the remote site list however I still receive an error.

The endpoint here is a dev sandbox I just created for testing purposes. 
endpoint: https://um1.lightning.force.com

```
public static void putCallout(){
    List<Case> cases = [select id, subject, status, Origin from case limit 5];
    String str = JSON.serialize(cases);
    System.debug('json str: ' + str);

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://um1.lightning.force.com/services/apexrest/Cases/*'); // webserivce callout
    request.setMethod('PUT');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    request.setBody(str);
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    while (response.getStatusCode() == 302) {
        request.setEndpoint(response.getHeader('Location'));
        response = new Http().send(request);
    }
    if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
        System.debug('Response str: ' + response.getBody());
    }
    else{
        System.debug('Response is not what we expected: ' + response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I still get the following error:

```
 System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://um1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/*
```

Comment: where are you setting up auth info for another org in this?

Comment: I know it sounds silly but I haven't set up auth in the org. Is there some docs you can link me to?

Comment: https://www.sfdc-lightning.com/2019/01/salesforce-rest-api-integration.html

Comment: Learn about and use a [Named Credential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've got a different address here:

```
 https://um1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/
```

to here:

```
 https://um1.lightning.force.com/services/apexrest/Cases/*
```

It's giving a 302 to the first request, you have an automated rerequest, but you haven't added the redirect url to your allowed settings.

Add - 'https://um1.salesforce.com/' url to allowed remote site.

Comment: Thanks. I get a 401 error after adding named credentials and Authentication Settings for External Systems. Any ideas?

Comment: If it is just for testing purposes, you can add the rest resource to a sites page then hit up the resource through a site url without having to auth in. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html